# How to control flow tree

Tags: java, if-statement, control-flow

When this code is run it will continue to run even if you enter "y" in the if-else tree. How can I fix it so it does its task, which is to tell you how to fix a simple router issue?

```
import java.util.*;

public class WifiTest
{
    public static void main(String [] args){

    //Set up the global variables and such
    String input;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    //Do We need to fix the connection?
    System.out.println("Is your wifi bad? y/n: ");
    input = scanner.nextLine();

    //If ELSE TREE

    if (input == "n"){
        System.out.println("There is no problem");    
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Reset and reboot the Computer, did it fix it?: y/n");
        input = scanner.nextLine();
        if (input == "y") {
        System.out.println("Now it is fixed");
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("Reboot the Router and try again, did that fix the problem? y/n : ");
        input = scanner.nextLine();
            if (input == "y"){
        System.out.println("Now it is fixed");
        }
            else {
            System.out.println("Make sure the cables between the router a modem are firm, did that fix it? y/n: ");
            input = scanner.nextLine();
                if (input == "y"){
                System.out.println("Now it is fixed");
            }
                else{
            System.out.println("Move the router to a new location, did that fix the problem? y/n: ");
            input = scanner.nextLine();
                    if (input == "y"){
                System.out.println("Now it is fixed");
            }
                    else{
                System.out.print("Get a New Router");
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use .equals or .equalsIgnoreCase when comparing strings.

Comment: And also press enter after pressing y or n